# Connect to an Oracle Database from Poco ODBC on a Linux machine

Tags: linux, oracle, odbc

I'd like to connect to an Oracle Database (11.2) located on a known server. Currently, I can connect to that database with Pro*C or OCCI, but I now need to create the connection from ODBC.

I succefully installed and configured ODBC on my machine : I can connect to my database from my shell with isql. I wrote two configuration files, /etc/odbc.ini and /etc/odbcinst.ini that contain information about my connection (password, user ID, URL, port...) and my driver (.so library file location).

However, I cannot connect to that same server from my C++ code, using Poco. I am asked for a connection string, but whatever I write in this connection string, my test program fails.

When I write "DSN={...};" or "Driver={...}", I get a segfault from inside sqlora.so.
When I ommit these two parameters, I get, of course, an exception with message

> Connection attempt failed: Connection:Not applicable
>
> Server:Not applicable
>
> ODBC Diagnostic record #1:
>
> SQLSTATE = IM002
>
> Native Error Code = 0
>
> [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified

I don't know how I should format my connection string, and www.connectionstrings.com doesn't seem to tell anything about connecting to oracle with ODBC from a Linux Machine.

Thanks for helping me, and please excuse my broken english.

Comment: Your english is excellent. If you hadn't mentioned it I would have had no idea you were not a native english speaker. On the ODBC front - what happens if you just enter the name of the data source, without the "DSN={}"?

Comment: Thanks Bob :) The result is weird. I was not sure of what was the DSN was, so I tried to indicate the name between brackets in my  /etc/odbc.ini. I got the same text error. I then tried to indicate the one at the line DSN=... in the same file, which is "OracleODBC-11g", and still got the same error. But when I tried "DSN=OracleODBC-11g", instead of getting a segfault, I still got this error, which might be a progress. Thanks for helping !